# How to convert value in dictionary from string to int

Tags: python, string, dictionary, integer

I have a list of dictionaries, where both the key and value are strings.
I am importing the data from a CSV file.
The dictionaries look like this:

```py
{'1A': '1',
 '1B': '1',
 '1C': '2'}
```

I would like to change the values into integers.

I have looked around for a solution but I don't seem to find anything that works.

This is my code (the list is called 'buyers'):

```
for i in buyers:
    for k, v in i.items():
        i[v] = int(i[v])
```

I receive this error:

```
i[v] = int(i[v])

KeyError: '1'
```

I'm not sure what to do because it says my error is the '1', which seems to me like it should be able to be converted into an int.

Comment: you're using the value as a key in the assignment

Comment: Use the key as index: i[k]

Comment: Do you mean `i[k] = int(i[v])` ? `k` is your key, `v` is your value. You are trying to do lookup in dictionary using value as its key

Answer (score 2):

You can use list and dict comprehensions.

```
buyers = [
    {'1A' : '1', '1B' : '1', '1C' : '2'},
    {'2A' : '2', '2B' : '4', '2C' : '3'}
]


result = [
    {key: int(val) for key, val in d.items()}
    for d in buyers
]

print(result)
```

Output

```
[{'1A': 1, '1B': 1, '1C': 2}, {'2A': 2, '2B': 4, '2C': 3}]
```

Comment: this method worked for coverting the values to integers, but it only prints the last dictionary repeatedly 5 times (for reference, I have a total of 54 dictionaries)

output:
[{1C': 1, '2C': 1, '3E': 1, 'PRODUCT NUMBER': 27, 'Week': 2},... X 5

Comment: This is strange as the method suggested creates a brand new list of the newly composed dictionaries, whereas keys and values are taken from the original ones. Can you review the original ``buyers`` list for the duplicates?

Comment: Yes sorry I wasn't clear, there are many duplicates, otherwise I'd have it all in one list. so I assume what is happening is the values are being rewritten in the dictionary.
For each dictionary, the keys are {'1A','1B','1C','1D','1E','2A',.....,'3C'}, and its likely that many of the keys are to have the same value

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `i[v] = int(i[v])` to  `i[k] = int(v)`

```
dict1  = {'1A' : '1', '1B' : '1', '1C' : '2'} 

for k, v in dict1.items():
    dict1[k] = int(v)
print(dict1 )
```

output:

```
{'1A': 1, '1B': 1, '1C': 2}
```